# Enums from another class in C++ (with SFML)

Tags: c++, enums

I'm using this code:

```
void GameObjectManager::DrawHUD(sf::RenderWindow& renderWindow)
{
    std::map<std::string, VisibleGameObject*>::const_iterator itr = _gameObjects.begin();
    while (itr != _gameObjects.end())
    {
        //if (itr->second->GetObjectType() == VisibleGameObject::HUD)
        //{
            itr->second->Draw(renderWindow);
            itr++;
        //}
    }
}
```

To draw all elements of ObjectType HUD. ObjectType is an enum in my other class VisibleGameObject. If I use the slashes in my code (so  when I don't check for the enum) everything works fine. But when I only want to draw objects of ObjectType HUD my program just gets stuck in Debug mode. I don't get any errors in debug or anything. It's just stuck on drawing the entire thing.

Does anybody see what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks in advance,

Xentro

Comment: Think about it, with that condition, the iterator only moves forward when the element is a hud element... You should use a for/foreach loop.

Comment: Omg that's so stupid, thanks for pointing this out.

Answer (score 3):

The problem you are having is if the condition is not true then you never increment the iterator.  If you never increment the iterator it will never be equal to `end()`.  You need to always increment the iterator and in your if statement do your processing:

```
void GameObjectManager::DrawHUD(sf::RenderWindow& renderWindow)
{
    std::map<std::string, VisibleGameObject*>::const_iterator itr = _gameObjects.begin();
    while (itr != _gameObjects.end())
    {
        if (itr->second->GetObjectType() == VisibleGameObject::HUD)
        {
            itr->second->Draw(renderWindow);
        }
        itr++;  // unconditional increment.
    }
}
```

If you want you can use ranged based for loops from C++11 and up like:

```
void GameObjectManager::DrawHUD(sf::RenderWindow& renderWindow)
{
    for (auto & e : _gameObjects)
    {
        if (e.second->GetObjectType() == VisibleGameObject::HUD)
            e.second->Draw(renderWindow);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks so much, really a rookie mistake there :s

Comment: That really should be a for/foreach loop though